# Procedure/Etiquette for No-Call No-Show Coworker

Tags: friends, work-environment, coworkers, professionalism, acceptable-behavior

My coworker, superior, and friend did not show up to work this morning. What is the standard or accepted procedure for checking in on them? No-call no-shows are not taken lightly in this organization, and they are atypical for this person as well.

I sent the following text/call combo:

- After 30 minutes late, I texted "Are you coming in today?"
- After 1 hour late, I attempted a phone call
- After 2.5 hours late, I texted "I'm a little worried - is everything ok?"

What else can I do? I am truly concerned but I do not want to make a bad impression by repeatedly attempting contact on their cell phone.

Comment: are your coworker, superior, and friend all one person?

Comment: Also, you say this person is your superior. Have you asked *their* superior to find out whether this person is actually a no-call no-show? what are the details surrounding how you found out this is the situation?

Comment: So far, have all your attempts been to the same channel? Can you email (might be checked on a laptop or a different phone) or FB message, or call a landline? Do you have a mutual friend who might know other ways to reach the person?

Answer (score 2):

The spacing between your responses isn't overbearing and repetitive, given the circumstances.  I find that a gap of around 30 minutes to an hour between contact attempts is acceptable, but you should also stop or slow down after a few hours of no contact.  Your friend could possibly have had an offsite meeting that you were unaware of where he turned his phone off in order to limit distractions.

Again I can't really speak on what actually is going on with your friend but I would slow down on your attempts to contact him and ask his superior to find out if he actually is a no-call-no-show, as Link0352 said in his comment.